# How to turn this class using hooks

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am working on a project using aws-amplify and I ran across the docs for amplify to take the users file and display it. I attempted to change this into a functional component and use hooks but I am at a loss. Code below thanks for any advice and help.

```
class ImageViewer extends Component {
  handleUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const path = file.name;
    Storage.put(path, file).then(() => this.setState({ path }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="rounded-circle user-profile-img shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div>
          {this.state && <S3Image path={this.state.path} />}
        </div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleUpload.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you having issues with? If you want to know how state works in hooks, look up `useState`. If you want to know how custom functions (like the `handleUpload` one) work, have a look at `useCallback`. With those two, you can easily convert this to a function component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const ImageViewer = () => {
  const [path, setPath] = React.useState('');

  const handleUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const path = file.name;
    Storage.put(path, file)
      .then(() => setPath(path));
  }

    return (
      <div className="rounded-circle user-profile-img shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div>
          {path && <S3Image path={path} />}
        </div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleUpload} />
      </div>
    );
}
```